# pkgdown vignette code chunk spacing

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pkgdown

I'm having issues with code chunk output when running `pkgdown::build_site()` with all default options. Chunks are rendered in [html content](https://mountainmath.github.io/cancensus/articles/Making_maps_with_cancensus.html) with superfluous white space in between every line of code. For example:

````
```{r, message = FALSE}
library(leaflet)
leaflet(toronto) %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addPolygons()
```
````

Comes out as:

```
library(leaflet)


leaflet(toronto) %>% 


  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%


  addPolygons()
```

Or, in screenshot form:

[image]

I haven't faced this issue in html content generated by `blogdown`, although I understand that's an independent package, and the `README.md` file renders just fine as well.

I haven't been able to find any mention of spacing in pkgdown code chunks, and I'm wondering where I can start troubleshooting this.

The YAML section of the vignette uses default entries:

```
---
title: "Vignette Title"
author: "Autho"
date: "11/22/2017"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Vignette Title}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

And the setup chunk is standard as well.

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = "#>"
)
```
````

---

Session details:

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] leaflet_1.1.0      ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 cancensus_0.1.5    bindrcpp_0.2      
[5] sf_0.5-5           dplyr_0.7.4        rgdal_1.2-15       sp_1.2-5          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13       lattice_0.20-35    class_7.3-14       assertthat_0.2.0  
 [5] rprojroot_1.2      digest_0.6.12      mime_0.5           R6_2.2.2          
 [9] plyr_1.8.4         backports_1.1.0    evaluate_0.10.1    e1071_1.6-8       
[13] httr_1.3.1         rlang_0.1.4        rematch_1.0.1      lazyeval_0.2.1    
[17] curl_2.8.1         rstudioapi_0.7     whisker_0.3-2      callr_1.0.0       
[21] rmarkdown_1.7      pkgdown_0.1.0.9000 desc_1.1.1         labeling_0.3      
[25] devtools_1.13.4    readr_1.1.1        udunits2_0.13      stringr_1.2.0     
[29] htmlwidgets_0.9    munsell_0.4.3      shiny_1.0.3        compiler_3.4.1    
[33] httpuv_1.3.5       pkgconfig_2.0.1    htmltools_0.3.6    highlight_0.4.7.2 
[37] tibble_1.3.4       roxygen2_6.0.1     viridisLite_0.2.0  crayon_1.3.4      
[41] withr_2.1.0.9000   MASS_7.3-47        commonmark_1.4     grid_3.4.1        
[45] jsonlite_1.5       xtable_1.8-2       gtable_0.2.0       DBI_0.7           
[49] magrittr_1.5       units_0.4-6        scales_0.5.0.9000  stringi_1.1.5     
[53] xml2_1.1.1         RColorBrewer_1.1-2 tools_3.4.1        glue_1.2.0        
[57] purrr_0.2.4        hms_0.3            crosstalk_1.0.0    pkgload_0.0.0.9000
[61] yaml_2.1.14        colorspace_1.3-2   classInt_0.1-24    memoise_1.1.0     
[65] knitr_1.17         bindr_0.1
```

Comment: I cloned your repository and also performed `pkgdown::build_site()` an did not see this extra lines. Perhaps update your R version to 3.4.2, the recent one?

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that, but I'm seeing the same as before. I suspect it's somewhere in conversion between .Rmd and html.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the space issue is present when knitting the specific page in question without using `pkgdown::build_site()`?

Comment: Similar to J_F comment, I am unable to repliace, lines such as `<div class="sourceLine" id="cb1-2" data-line-number="2">` show up in your html, but not mine when I try to replicate.  Here is the context where the extra line is showing up `<span class="kw">library</span>(cancensus)</div>
<div class="sourceLine" id="cb1-2" data-line-number="2">
<span class="kw">library</span>(sf)</div>` .  Though not clear to me what would be causing this.

Comment: Thanks @jmuhlenkamp - The space issue is not present when rendered on its own via `rmarkdown::render(...)`. I also just tried to build the page on a completely clean install on a different osx machine and still had double spaced code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have upgraded to Pandoc 2.0, [which is unnecessary](https://yihui.name/en/2017/11/pandoc-2/) at the moment. The easiest fix (also what I'd recommend) is to remove your own version of Pandoc. The slightly harder way is to report this issue to the author of **pkgdown**, and wait for a fix (for Pandoc 2.0), which would be similar to the [fix here in **rmarkdown**](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1200). If **pkgdown** allows custom CSS, you can also fix it by yourself:

```
.sourceLine {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly the issue. I did in fact just recently install Pandoc 2.0 - I didn't realize that it just came out and that `pkgdown` still relied on the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the line-height under the style specified for the html `code` element, the element that represents a fragment of computer code on an html page.

According to the documentation for `pkgdown::build_site`,

> If you want to do minor customisation of your pkgdown site, the easiest way is to add pkgdown/extra.css and pkgdown/extra.js. These will be automatically copied to docs/ and inserted into the  after the default pkgdown CSS and JSS.

So, adding a file called 'extra.css' containing the code below should do the trick:

```
/*-- Extra CSS for code chunks --*/

pre, code {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.0; /*-- Change line-height as required --*/
}
```

The code snippet below illustrates the effects of changing *line-height*.

```css
/*Using two class selectors to illustrate the example*/

pre,
code.wide {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 2.0;
}

pre,
code.narrow {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code class="wide">
  1st line of code
  2nd line of code
  
  3rd line of code
  </code>
</pre>

<pre>
  <code class="narrow">
  1st line of code
  2nd line of code
  
  3rd line of code
  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. This worked as one way to fix the issue, but I was more worried about why computers were rendering in a way different from everybody elses and it was the case that I jumped the gun on a new installation of pandoc as @yihui pointed out.